# How to remove a string from a list python

Tags: python, string, list

Is it possible to remove the string and just have the list

```
data = [
"50,bird,corn,105.4,"
"75,cat,meat,10.3,"
"100,dog,eggs,1000.5,"
]
```

would like it to look like this

```
data = [
50,'bird','corn',105.4,
75,'cat','meat',10.3,
100,'dog','eggs',1000.5,
]
```

Comment: what did you try, what troubles do you have?

Comment: The list in `data` is improperly formatted. How did you arrive at your initial data structure?

Comment: i try data[1].strip("") didn't work - not sure what can be used

Comment: input = open(data.txt, 'r') data = input.read().splitlines()

Comment: `words = ','.join(data).split(',')` after fixing your `data` (this is the lazy way to do it - it creates on big string seperated by , and then splits at , - less effective then the answer posted)

Answer (score 5):

```
out = []
for x in data:
  for e in x.split(","):
    out.append(e)
```

What does this do? It splits each element (`x`) in `data` on the comma, picks out each of those separate tokens (`e`), and puts them in the variable (`out.append`).

Comment: Thank you for the help but this is split the data at the "," but im just trying to remove this encap " "

Answer (score 4):

```
new_data = []
for i in data:
    new_data.extend(i.split(','))
new_data
```

Do note that there might be issues (for example, you have one last comma with nothing after it, so it generates a '' string as the last element in the new array).

If you want to specifically convert the numbers to ints and floats, maybe there is a more elegant way, but this will work (it also removes empty cells if you have excess commas):

```
new_data = []
for i in data:
    strings = i.split(',')
    for s in strings:
        if (len(s)>0):
            try:
                num = int(s)
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    num = float(s)
                except ValueError:
                    num = s
            new_data.append(num)
new_data
```

Comment: thank you for the help but im getting this '50'
'bird'
'corn'
'105.4'
'75'
'cat'
'meat'
'10.3,'
'100'
'dog'
'eggs'
'1000.5'

Comment: you mean that you want to transform the numbers in the string into numbers?

Answer (score 0):

split each string (this gives you an array of the segments between "," in each string):

```
str.split(",")
```

and add the arrays together

Answer (score 0):

Because each string in the list has a trailing comma, you can simply put it back together as a single string and split it again on commas.  In order to get actual numeric items in the resulting list, you could do this:

```
import re
data = [
    "50,bird,corn,105.4,"
    "75,cat,meat,10.3,"
    "100,dog,eggs,1000.5,"
]
numeric = re.compile("-?\d+[\.]\d*$")
data = [ eval(s) if numeric.match(s) else s for s in "".join(data).split(",")][:-1]

data # [50, 'bird', 'corn', 105.4, 75, 'cat', 'meat', 10.3, 100, 'dog', 'eggs', 1000.5]
```